# "Alert" and "if" changes behaviour of dom copying from iframe to div

Tags: javascript, caching, iframe, copy

Tried to make a little old school ajax (iframe-javascript) script. A bit of mootools is used for DOM navigation

**Description**:

HTML:

1 iframe called "buffer"

1 div called "display"

JAVASCRIPT: (short: copy iframe content into a div on the page)

1) onLoad on iframe triggers handler(), a counter makes sure it only run once
(this is because otherwise firefox will go into feedback loop. What i think happens: iframe on load > handler() > copyBuffer > change src of iframe , and firefox takes that as an onload again)

2) copybuffer() is called, it sets src of iframe then copies iframe content into div, then erases iframe content

THE CODE:

---

```
count=0;
function handler(){

if (count==0){
copyBuffer();
count++;
}

}

function copyBuffer(){


$('buffer').set('src','http://www.somelink.com/');

if (window.frames['buffer'] && $('display') ) { 

$('display').innerHTML = window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML;
window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML="";
}

}
```

---

**problems**:

QUESTION 1) nothing happens, the content is not loaded into the div. But if i either:

A) remove the counter and let the script run in a feedback loop:  the content is suddenly copied into the div, but off course there is a feedback loop going on, you can see it keeps loading in the status bar.

OR

B) insert an alert in the copyBuffer function. The content is copied, without the feedback loop.

why does this happen?

QUESTION 2) The If wrapped around the copying code i got from a source on the internet. I am not sure what it does? If i remove it the code does not work in: Safari and Chrome.

Many thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE:**

Like the answers said i have created an event handler. They used jQuery, i have made one in **mootools**:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    $('buffer').addEvent('load', function(){

        $('display').set('html',window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML) 
        window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML="";

    }).set('src','somelink');

});
```

**Bonus question:**

3) Im new at stackoverflow (what an amazing place!), is it better if i make new threads for follow up questions?

Comment: 3) You are right: one (not three, five, seven) question per question is natural :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe has not loaded the page when you try to access it, so it cannot get the contents..

I believe the following would work, by adding a load handler on the iframe and do the copy inside that..

```
function handler(){
   $('buffer').load( function(){copyBuffer();} ).attr('src','http://www.somelink.com/');
}

function copyBuffer(){
   if (window.frames['buffer'] && $('display') ) 
    { 
       $('display').innerHTML = window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML;
       window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML="";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you guys were both right! i have updated the question with a bonus question and a mootools script.

Comment: Hi, i have a little semantics question. The handler works but, when looking at code code from a logical standpoint doesn't it say:
when 'buffer' has loaded run function copyBuffer, then set src?

but what it _does_ is:

set 'buffer' src, then when it has loaded run function.

What am i misinterpreting?

Comment: if you notice the parenthesis, it actually says..  find the buffer element with `$('buffer')` assign a handler to the load event `.load(...handler ...)` ( *handler being the function inside the parenthesis, which will be called when the buffer fires the load event* ), and finally set the attribute src to some value `.attr('src',...)` which will  initiate the loading of the url, and when loaded will fire the load event ( *which will get caught by out handler* ).. it could break to multiple lines, but you will have to set the load handler before setting the src, or you might miss the load event.

Comment: @lowkey, i added a comment, but I used maximum chars and could not add your name to notify you, lol...

Answer (score 0):

> B) insert an alert in the copyBuffer
>   function. The content is copied,
>   without the feedback loop.

According to your description there is some sort of delay needed for your code to execute correctly and alert just gives the delay needed.
To be more precise, it seems to me that timespan between `$('buffer').set('src','http://www.somelink.com/');` and `$('display').innerHTML = window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML;` is not long enough for the buffer to get its  source loaded completely.

You should think about handling appropriate event in order to be sure that everything has already been loaded before your code fires.

For instance, you can rewrite your code in the following way:

```
function handler(){    
    $('buffer').load( function(){
        if (count==0){
            copyBuffer();
            count++;
        }
    }).attr('src','http://www.somelink.com/');    
}

function copyBuffer(){

    //$('buffer').set('src','http://www.somelink.com/');

    if (window.frames['buffer'] && $('display') ){    
        $('display').innerHTML = window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML;
        window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML="";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you guys were both right! i have updated the question with a bonus question and a mootools script.